# Strange characters appearing in HTML code

Tags: html

We have a chatroom on our website and it allows us to enter text below the chatroom and switch back and forth between HTML and regular text with a checkbox: "Check this box to use WYSIWYG editing". The inputted text looks fine in the editor but after we hit save there are "Â" characters scattered through out the paragraphs.

Example:

```
Â 474theMiX.comÂ©Â Radio - MiX Virtual Studio Chat CommunityÂ©
```

How and why is this occurring, and can we stop this from happening?

Comment: How do you expect us to help you with no code provided? Are we supposed to just guess? Well, my guess is character encoding.

Comment: here is part of the code: <div> <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="i1106.photobucket.com/albums/h371/DJ_Hip/Website/…; alt="" border="0" style="margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;" /><span style="font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;"> </span></div>

Comment: Please edit the question to add that additional information

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the content type is set to UTF-8

`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`

or for HTML5

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: here is part of the code: <div>                                                                                                                  <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://i1106.photobucket.com/albums/h371/DJ_Hip/Website/addtext_com_MjIwNDMyNDc0ODg_zps71ab4acd.png" alt="" border="0" style="margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;" /><span style="font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;"> </span></div>

Comment: if the reply has helped and resolved your issue, please mark it as the answer.